# Insert Formula with Variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a variable into formula using VBA. I've referenced [How to pass an integer variable into a vba formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972695/how-to-pass-an-integer-variable-into-a-vba-formula) this question and tried implementing that in my if formula. 
=IF (startCell >0, startcell+confirmed, endcell+confirmed)

but I'm still unsure and getting an error.

My code is the following:

```
headerrow = 7
startCell = 8
endCell = 3
confirmed= 5

DDSS_Actual.Cells(headerrow + 3, 3).Formula = "=IF(" & startCell & ">" & endCell & ","& startCell & "+" &confirmed&", " & endCell & "+" &confirmed &")"
```

Thanks.

Comment: *startCell* is 8 and 8 is not a cell. Do you mean cells(startCell, 3)?

Comment: @Jeeped   Nope. startCell is a integer and its a variable that will change. it isnt pointing to a cell. i shouldnt have named it startcell.

Comment: Hard-coding numbers into a 'formula' is pretty useless. Why wouldn't you adjudicate the criteria and write the result into the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put spaces before and after the `&`

which makes it

```
DDSS_Actual.Cells(headerrow + 3, 3).Formula = "=IF(" & startCell & ">" & endCell & "," & startCell & "+" & confirmed & "," & endCell & "+" & confirmed & ")"
```

Comment: If i change it a little to make my formula >0 and i tried this, changing >end row to >0 but i get errors :  DDSS_Actual.Cells(headerrow + 3, DDSS_InvQTY).Formula = "=IF(" & Delta_val & " " > " & 0 & ", " & Delta_val & "+" & confirmed & "," & Delta_val2 & "+" & confirmed & ")"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do i write the formula to change the ">" & endCell & to ">" 0 ? I tried and i got errors

Comment: Make it ">0". You should have tried harder to figure this out yourself.

Comment: yes i should have tried harder. i was going to just declare endcell = 0. And thank you